# Разить и разница

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Общий ли корень у слов "разить" и "разница"? Вроде как, значения разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, эти слова не родственны.

Разить - восходит к индоевропейскому raz- резать, резаный.
Разница - к славянскому роз- разный, врозь и т.д.